# How does "Closure" affect my nested traversal of dom nodes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pointers

I understand closure somewhat, but sometimes I can't seem to get it right.  I believe this to be the culprit here... Since i'm traversing tho, i'm not sure if closure is necessary or possible.

So I have to parse some external markup that looks like this:

```
<h2>Fried Calamari</h2>
<dd>Price:$8.95</dd>
<dd>Pan-fried calamari served with our delicious homemade tomato sauce.</dd>
<h3>Extra Sauce</h3>
<dd>Required:0 / Up To:99</dd>
<ol>
<li><dt>Extra Sauce</dt><dd>Price:$0.99</dd></li>
</ol>
<h2>Fried Zuchinni</h2>
<dd>Price:$6.95</dd>
<dd>Tossed with garlic and herbs. Served with a side of tomato sauce.</dd>
<h3>Extra Sauce</h3>
<dd>Required:0 / Up To:99</dd>
<ol>
<li><dt>Extra Sauce</dt><dd>Price:$0.99</dd></li>
</ol>
<h2>Eggplant Rollatini Appetizer</h2>
<dd>Price:$7.95</dd>
<dd>Fresh rolled eggplant filled with Ricotta and topped with tomato sauce and melted Mozzarella.</dd>
<h3>Extra Sauce</h3>
<dd>Required:0 / Up To:99</dd>
<ol>
<li><dt>Extra Sauce</dt><dd>Price:$0.99</dd></li>
</ol>
<h2>Mozzarella Sticks</h2>
<dd>Price:$6.95</dd>
<dd>Classic Mozzarella sticks served with a side of tomato sauce.</dd>
<h3>Extra Sauce</h3>
<dd>Required:0 / Up To:99</dd>
<ol>
<li><dt>Extra Sauce</dt><dd>Price:$0.99</dd></li>
</ol>
<h2>Buffalo Rock Shrimp</h2>
<dd>Price:$9.75</dd>
<dd>Crispy rock shrimp toasted in our signature buffalo sauce. Served with Blue cheese crumbles.</dd>
<h3>Extra Dressing</h3>
<dd>Required:0 / Up To:99</dd>
<ol>
<li><dt>Extra Dressing</dt><dd>Price:$0.99</dd></li>
</ol>
```

Here's my js using jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('h2').each(function(i) {
     //to hold the info
     var itemDetail = new Object();
     //h2's contain the name
     itemDetail['name'] = $(this).html();       

     // but dd's contain price description and other
     // and we need to traverse all <dd> tags for each <h2> 
     $(this).siblings('dd').each(function(){             
         var itemInfo = $(this).html();
         var priceLabel = itemInfo.slice(0,7);
         var priceValue = itemInfo.slice(7);
         if (priceLabel='Price:$'){
             itemDetail['price'] = priceValue;
         }else{
             // discard required info (leaving description)
             if (itemInfo.slice(0,9) != 'Required:')
             //descriptions don't have a label 
             itemDetail['description'] = itemInfo;
         }
     });
     console.log(itemDetail)
 }); 
});
```

if i step thru the traversals using alert() on priceLabel and priceValue, the logic echo's the correct values (specifically priceValue is a numberwhen priceLabel matches the criteria, but when I log the object, i'm not getting info for each iteration of the inner traversal.  Instead priceLabel is equal to the .slice() of the final  iteration.

Is there a better way to avoid this or use closure to force info into my objects...

Comment: Nice how high rep'd poster was able to retract his "answer" when i commented on how it was not accurate.  I can't mark down yet, but it's pretty lame that you withdrew rather than mark up my question so i can get some feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of issues:

- The `=` does *assignment* but you used it for comparison instead of using `==` or `===`
- You used `.siblings('dd')` which is giving you *all* the `dd` elements, instead of just the next adjacent ones. With your current markup, you can use `nextUntil(':not(dd)')` instead.

```
 $('h2').each(function(i) {
     var itemDetail = new Object();
     itemDetail['name'] = $(this).html();       

       // ----v---get next siblings of "h2" until on that is not "dd" is reached
     $(this).nextUntil(':not(dd)').each(function(){             
         var itemInfo = $(this).html();
         var priceLabel = itemInfo.slice(0,7);
         var priceValue = itemInfo.slice(7);

              //--------v----------- use == instead of =
         if (priceLabel == 'Price:$'){
             itemDetail['price'] = priceValue;
         }else{
             if (itemInfo.slice(0,9) != 'Required:')
             itemDetail['description'] = itemInfo;
         }
     });
     console.log(itemDetail)
 });
```

---

**EDIT:**

If your markup is consistent the way it shows, then you can shorten your code a bit like this:

```
 $('h2').each(function(i) {
     var itemDetail = new Object();
     itemDetail['name'] = $(this).html();       

     var dds = $(this).nextUntil(":not(dd)");
     itemDetail['price'] = dds.eq(0).html().slice(7);
     itemDetail['description'] = dds.eq(1).html();
     console.log(itemDetail);
 });
```

Or even shorter using an object literal:

```
 $('h2').each(function(i) {
     var dds = $(this).nextUntil(":not(dd)");
     var itemDetail = {
                name: $(this).html(),
               price: dds.eq(0).html().slice(7),
         description: dds.eq(1).html()
     };
     console.log(itemDetail);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks so much... Darn that assignment! It still get's me and I KNOW it's often the source of my hard to find bugs... Thanks for the tip.  Yeah, there's no guarantee they'll be consecutive, but nifty selectors are always good tho have in the arsenal.  Thanks again.

Comment: @AdrianB: You're welcome. FYI, I updated my answer with a second solution that shortens the code a bit by getting rid of the inner `.each()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you declared itemDetail inside the function you passed on your first .each, its scope is limited to that function(and the functions you made inside that function).

Also, you're overwriting  itemDetail['price'] and itemDetail['description'] over and over again as you step through  $(this).siblings('dd'), is this intentional?

Comment: There will only be one price and one detail for each 'set' of dd values, so yes.  And would not the dd traversal have access to  itemDetail since it is declared in the 'wrapping' function?

Comment: yes it(the function in your 'dd' traversal) will have access to itemDetail.

Comment: which is why I believe this is more of a closure issue.  I had a poster just before you withdraw the same answer and mark up your answer...  Would you mind marking up the question, because I believe it is more complex than scope, which is what the first impression now seems to be here.

Comment: Would you agree then that your answer is not the answer.  Most viewers here are going to think this is an elementary question when in fact, closure within nested jQuery traversals seems to require intermediate to advanced javaScript ability.  I need help! Please help by rating up this question to get more visibility. thanks.

Comment: Closure is closure, there is nothing different when you do it in a jquery traversal. Can you update your question to include where you placed your alert call(the current one only has console.log)?

Comment: Ok, so the function which is the parameter of the .each() method... how would I extract that to be get closure? The alert was on priceLabel and priceValue within the <dd> traversal.  I'll update the question to reflect that.